# should do/should have done in the indirect speech

Tags: modal-verbs

> Look! The car's broken down again! I told you we ____ it before we
> left!
>
> 1 should have checked
>
> 2 should check

I think that both are correct. What's the difference?

Comment: Yes, both are correct, but you might say that the perfect is redundant because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by "before we left".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I told you we should check it before we left* - Before they set off, the speaker recommended checking something about the car, but it wasn't done.

*I told you we should have checked it...* - Earlier in the journey, the speaker wished that they had checked it before leaving (perhaps because the car had started to make a strange noise).

Comment: It occurred to me that in the second scenario it should be "I told you we should have checked it before we HAD LEFT".

Comment: No. As people have often commented on this forum, it's not necessary, and makes the sentence cumbersome, to use the perfect tense for _every_ verb, if using it once makes the meaning clear. **Check it before we left** is what we **should have** done.

Answer (score 1):

> ... I told you we ____ it before we left!

*should have checked* doesn't fit in OP's example as it is for a conversation after the breakdown, which may not be the OP's intention.

*should check* is possible:

> I told you we *should check* it before we left!

Also possible is

> I told you *to check* it before we left!

This last version (a request to check) means slightly different from that using *we should check* (a suggestion).

Comment: I kind of agree. But don't you think that it depends on what was said initially? If it was "We should have checked it before ..." then "should have checked" should remain.

Comment: Thanks, @user1425.  Yes, agreed.  If *We should have checked it before ...* was said earlier, we can repeat *should've checked*.  If the pre-trip conversation was *we should check it before we leave*, we use the *should check* version.